# Superscript text in Label

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to superscript a label in Xamarin Forms? In HTML I would use the `<sup>` tag. I want to superscript the text "min". So I can have the text "5min" with the "min" part superscripted.

Comment: look at FormattedText property.  I don't think it supports superscript, but you can mix font sizes for a similar effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jason for his idea of using `FormattedText` property. But since it doesn't support binding of the text, I put 2 labels together in a `StackLayout`, the superscript text in mirco font size:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="{Binding Minutes}">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="fonts/chsans/MyFont-Bold.ttf#MyFont-Bold" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                <Label Text="min" FontSize="Micro">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="fonts/chsans/MyFont-Regular.ttf#MyFont-Regular" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Label`'s `TextType` property to `Html`.

For example, to produce: x<sup>2</sup> + y

In XAML:

```
<Label Text="x&lt;sup&gt;&lt;small&gt;2&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sup&gt; + y" TextType="Html"/>
```

or

```
<Label TextType="Html">
    <![CDATA[
    x<sup><small>2</small></sup> + y
    ]]>
</Label>
```

In C#:

```
MyStackLayout.Children.Add(
    new Label {
        TextType=TextType.Html,
        Text="x<sup><small>2</small></sup> + y"
    });
```

Note that the <small> tag is optional.

For more information, see the "Display HTML" section of the `Label` documentation: [Xamarin.Forms Label: Display HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html)